# It is possible to get deb from jenkins before debian repo sync?

Tags: ros, deb, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I released new package. Build on jenkins.ros.org successfully completes. Where i can get these package(s) for inspection?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173958/it-is-possible-to-get-deb-from-jenkins-before-debian-repo-sync?/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each distro, there is a status page for debs (for indigo, it's http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html, for others, replace indigo with the distro). This will tell you what version is in what debian repository. The second column under each heading is the "ros-shadow-fixed" repository, which is probably what you want.

If you want to download an individual deb for inspection, you can find them at http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed, or you could update your /etc/apt/sources files to point at "ros-shadow-fixed" rather than "ros", which will allow you to install and test (but, of course, things might be broken -- the "fixed" in ros-shadow-fixed is kinda wishful thinking, not a guarantee)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3